# Will I earn Nintendo Points for digital purchases outside the eShop?

Tags: my-nintendo

Normally when you buy a digital game on the Nintendo Switch eShop, you receive [5% credit back](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28423/) as My Nintendo Gold Points.

If I purchase a digital copy of a Switch game outside of the eShop, (ie: [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XCZK149) or [GameStop](https://www.gamestop.com/nintendo-switch/games/shovel-knight-treasure-trove/143402)), will I still earn Nintendo Gold Points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will earn Gold Points if you buy a digital copy from retailers like Amazon or Gamestop.

> Gold Points can be earned by purchasing eligible digital games for
>   Nintendo Switch [...] from the official Nintendo website, Nintendo eShop, or
>   by redeeming a retailer-issued download code.

[Source](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16609)

You will get the usual 5% (of the undiscounted eShop price at the time of redemption) for download codes as well.

[Source](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/My-Nintendo/Gold-Point-usage-with-the-Nintendo-Switch/How-many-Gold-Points-do-I-receive-for-each-purchase-/How-many-Gold-Points-do-I-receive-for-each-purchase--1351068.html)

Comment: Also worth nothing that you can get Gold Points from physical purchases too, though only 1% instead of 5% [(link)](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22312/~/how-to-earn-my-nintendo-points-for-physical-software)

Comment: Do download codes earn the full 5% reward, or does it give a reduced amount like the 1% for physical games?

Comment: Added that info to my answer.

Comment: @TestingTest How do you know it gives the full 5%? I don't see that on the linked source.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Sorry, forgot to add the source, fixed it now.